Keyword spotting - List of possible approaches
My goal is to come with an algorithm, that is able to spot a dynamic keyword. For example, let's pick the keyword "monkey". Given an audio stream, I want to identify when "monkey" has been said by the speaker.
A simple approach is to extract MFCC features, and compare the sequences with DTW. This has many issues:

Sequences can be vastly different in length:
DTW distance is not a good similarity metric? For my test, the phrase "Blue monkey" had a larger distance than "Red squirrel" (similar sequence length).

I'm exploring different methods and would like which algorithms / tools are available to use. I would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction of state of the art.  I am happy to learn about deep learning methods, although my preference would be deterministic algorithms.
Requirements:

Zero-shot / dynamic keyword. I can select any keyword to spot.
I can pre-compute the MFCC for the keyword (by running TTS)
Ideally real-time


Welcome. This is a well studied problem and part of any voice assistant (Alexa, Siri, Hey Google, etc.). What research have you done and what have you found so far ?

Thank you. It more "Dynamic" keyword-spotting or zero-shot keyword picking, where I pick a keyword not present in the training data-set. I think that I need a speech encoder, followed by creating acoustic hidden features which are then compared to the acoustic features of the "Keyword". So I think I need a full ASR, but replace the decoder (that spits out tokens) with some distance comparison metric e.g. DTW?
